# Chromecast communication using JAVA/Android and Http

Tags: java, android, http-headers, chromecast

I'm trying to communicate with Chromecast using Http. I'm using [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/hardware-hacking/chromecast/chromecast-unofficial-api-information-t2788502) documentation about API methods and trying to execute an Youtube video on it. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/4785114) answer to execute a post call, for now I have:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        String urlParameters = "v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes();
        int postLenght = postData.length;
        //url is: new URL("http://192.168.25.99:8008/apps/YouTube")
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postLenght));
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This command execute properly but nothing happening in Chromecast.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you figure it executes properly? you never check the result of the request!

Comment: omg!? it executes without errors! but I will see.

Comment: You are right! when I call the response, the video plays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I just forgot to call the response:

```
String responseMessage = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
```

When I call this method, the video executes.